# AngularFire2 Retrieving Data Snapshot

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

Right now, I am unwrapping my data using the method [described in the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#retrieving-the-snapshot). However, the documentation states:

> **AngularFire2 unwraps the Firebase DataSnapshot by default**, but you can get the data as the original snapshot by specifying the preserveSnapshot option.

How would I be able to access the "default" unwrapping functionality (read: access the elements of `item`) without having the manually unwrap the data snapshot?

My data from Firebase looks like this:

```
{
  testObj : {
    firstName: "beckah",
    lastName: "s"
  }
}
```

My code (which works) is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController,
              public db: AngularFireDatabase ) {
    this.item = db.object('/testObj', { preserveSnapshot: true });
    this.item.subscribe(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
    });
  }
}
```

Which outputs

```
Object {firstName: "beckah", lastName: "s"}
```

How would I be able to do the exact same thing (console.log my `item` object) without manually unwrapping my snapshot like the documentation states is possible?

Is there some kind of `this.item.get("firstName")` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With AngularFire, you don't need to worry about snapshots at all. Just subscribe to the AngularObjectObservable, and it will feed you the object.

**angularfire2 version 4**

```
this.item$ = this.db.object('/item').subscribe(item => console.log(item));
```

**angularfire2 version 5**

```
this.item$ = this.db.object<Item>('/item').valueChanges().subscribe(item => console.log(item));
```

You should not subscribe in the constructor. Subscribe in `onNgInit`. Then make sure to unsubscribe in `onNgDestroy` to avoid memory leaks.

In many cases, you don't need to subscribe at all--let Angular do it in the template, using the `async` pipe:

**angularfire2 version 4**

```
// component
public item$: FirebaseObjectObservable<Item>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.item$ = this.db.object('/item');
}

// template
<div *ngIf="item$ | async as item">
  First name is {{item?.firstName}}.
</div>
```

**angularfire2 version 5**

```
// component
public item$: Observable<Item>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.item$ = this.db.object<Item>('/item').valueChanges();
}

// template
<div *ngIf="item$ | async as item">
  First name is {{ item?.firstName }}
</div>
```

Comment: When you reference `AngularObjectObservable`, do you mean `rxjs/Observable`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `FirebaseObjectObservable`, which is a subclass of `Observable`.

Comment: No problem :) In that case though, I don't think you can subscribe to a result and do an assignment at the same time. You'll get the error `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any>'`. But you can pop in an anonymous function in the second argument that console.logs and does an assignment. Regardless, this helped tremendously especially how to asychronously listen with the template.

Comment: Also, I can't edit your answer, but for others who find this answer helpful, it might be worth adding `{{ testObj$?.firstName }}` to show how to display a specific field